# Error MT9009: License information could not be verified

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

After upgrading Mac OS Mavericks to Yosemite I am getting this below error in Xamarin studio. Can anyone help me to come out from this situation.

Error MT9009: License information could not be verified. Please contact support@xamarin.com (MT9009)

Comment: As stated by the error message you need to contact Xamarin's support.

Comment: Yes, But anyone get the same i can fix issue through this forms. I have sent mail to them as well. If i get it soon ll share it here!!

Comment: Have you tried logging out, then logging back in and "re-activating"?